# Why is the drop in water pressure caused by air in water?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, fluid-statics, physical-chemistry

[image]First time

I connect some pipes, then I fill water pressure into the pipeline to 10 kg cm$^{-2}$, but the pressure became 9 kg cm$^{-2}$ on the next day, I think about pressure drop cause fill air in pipes.

[image]Second time

I install the air relief valve at the high point, then I wait for $30$ minutes, water pressure became 9.8 kg cm$^{-2}$, I closed the air relief valve, doing this will ensure that the pressure will not drop again the next day?

If water pressure became 9 kg cm$^{-2}$ the next day, but the pipes didn't leak, how to explain this happening?

Comment: Can you reword this: "...I think about pressure drop cause fill air in pipes..."?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the water pressure decreases when the water is cooled during the night.